# How can i know if user DENIED permission for GPS android

Tags: android

here is my code and it asks me for permission if i click Allow it works good but when the user clicks on DENY i want to get a result or log for denied
if user clicks "DENY" permission how can i set something on that 
    here is my code :

```
 LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    Location location;

    if (network_enabled) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ;


        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                1);


        location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(location!=null){
            lat = location.getLongitude();
            lon = location.getLatitude();

            Log.d("lat", "onCreate: "+lat+","+lon);
            txtLocation.setText(+lat+","+lon);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Latitude:"+lat+"\n"+"Longitude:"+lon);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();


        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    Log.d("", "onRequestPermissionsResult: "+requestCode);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+grantResults.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //user denied permission additionally you can check
                //ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale if user checked on "do not show again" while clicking deny
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First implement an onRequestPermissionResult like this:

```
@Override 
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION: { 
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty. 
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the 

            } else { 

               //user denied permission additionally you can check  
               //ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale if user checked on "do not show again" while clicking deny
            } 
            return; 
        } 

        // other 'case' lines to check for other 
        // permissions this app might request 
    } 
}
```

Comment: how to call onRequestPermissionsResult after implimenting the method

Comment: It will be called automatically when user presses on "allow" or "deny",

Comment: what is MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION ?

Comment: Please go through this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html to understand how to deal with runtime permission model on marshamallow onwards

Comment: can you plz check my question as i made changes in the code but it isnt working